# Getting a 'DLL' error when trying to install Node.js on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to install Node.js on Windows 7 64 bit and I'm getting an error at the beginning of the installation process. The error reads:

> *There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.*

As soon as I click on the downloaded file I see this error. How do I resolve this so I can download Node.js?

Comment: Did you try the binary and msi packages from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Once try to clean your temp folder and disable your antivirus for few minutes, hope It works

Answer (score 7):

I have managed the problem running installation file from cmd as Admin:
msiexec -i path_to_msi\node-v10.16.2-x64.msi

Comment: This tip helped me to install Node on the second computer on Windows 10. The only useful advice on this thread, lots of thanks!

Comment: This helped me as well.. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. Clean `TEMP` Folder
2. Disable your antivirus for 10 mins or so.
3. Then do the below steps.
4. Go to `C:>users>"UserName">AppData>Local>Temp`
5. Right Click on `Temp` and go to `Properties`
6. Select Security Tab
7. Select the User and check the permission and control give the user full control by Checking Full Control on permission.
8. Go Ahead and Install `Node.js` and Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

I think it has something to do with folder permission, please refer to here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/478631/dll-could-not-be-run-for-msi-installers

Answer (score 3):

Deleting C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Temp folder has solved it for me as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3431)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Node.js to work (particularly npm which is essential for anything non-trivial).

There is an up-to-date list of the something large set of dependencies for node-gyp (the tool for building native libraries for Node.js) on Windows here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

Comment: Would I download [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that a virus scanner is getting in the way. Try disabling any virus scanners and retry the installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, as posted on a closed Node.js GitHub issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12311 thus:

> node is xcopyable, just unzip your preferred archive and setx the path

1. To go https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v7.x/ (or navigate to your desired version).
2. Pick an archive (in the case of the GitHub issue OP: node-v7.8.0-win-x64.zip)
3. Unzip to your favorite location (e.g. C:\Program Files\Node, or c:\bin\nodejs)
4. Open a command prompt and run SETX [/S] Path "%Path%;[your chosen node directory]"

   - [/S] for adding for all users (and the SYSTEM user)
   - [your chosen node directory] from step 3

That's it. Open a new console and type node -V or npm -V, should work

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to install node with nvm on an old windows server 2008. The version I was trying to install was incompatible with that OS.